# GHC not deducing the way I would like it to :-(

Tags: haskell

```
chainQuery :: (Enum a, Integral a, Ord b) => a -> b -> [c]
chainQuery n min = map length $ filter beatingLength $ map chain [1..n]
  where
    beatingLength :: [a] -> Bool
    beatingLength xs = length xs > min
    chain :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
    chain n
      | n <= 1 = [n]
      | even n = n:(chain $ div n 2)
      | otherwise = n:(chain $ n * 3 + 1)
```

1. In the code sample above why isn't GHC able to deduce that 'c' is an Int by looking at the type definition for length?
2. Why does GHC need to know anything about 'b' other than that it is an Ord?
3. Is there a better way to write this function?

Comment: As hammer said, GHC is saying "This user is not deducing the way I would like him or her to :-("  Perhaps that should be the error message.

Comment: fromIntegral allows me to have more generic types so that is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. GHC is able to infer `[Int]` as the result type for the function. The problem is that you've claimed in your type signature that it should be *more* polymorphic, that the result could be a list of any type, which does not make sense since the return value comes from the `map length` so it must have type `[Int]`. This is what GHC is complaining about when it says `Could not deduce (c ~ Int)`.
2. You're comparing `min` to `length xs`. The greater-than operator has the type `(>) :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool`, which means that both sides must be the same type. The type of `length xs` is `Int`, so this forces `min` to be `Int` as well.
3. Probably. For example, you can map the length before doing the filtering. This makes it easy to use an operator section instead of your `beatingLength` function. You can also move the parenthesis to save a use of `$` to make the code a bit neater.

   ```
   chainQuery n min = filter (> min) $ map (length . chain) [1..n]
       where chain n | n <= 1    = [1]
                     | even n    = n : chain (n `div` 2)
                     | otherwise = n : chain (3*n + 1)
   ```

For reference, the easiest way to solve a problem like this is to remove your type signature and see what type was inferred in GHCi using the `:t` command. In this case, the inferred type is

```
*Main> :t chainQuery 
chainQuery :: Integral a => a -> Int -> [Int]
```

Comment: Also, it's a matter of preference but I would change the variable name, `min`, to something that won't shadow a pre-existing definition (`min` is a function in the `Ord` class).

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed, and GHC warns about this if you compile with the `-Wall` option. This enables all warnings and is generally a good idea to use along with [HLint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) to catch potential problems early.